# AWS Lambda + RabbitMQ: Unsupported engine type: RabbitMQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, rabbitmq

I am trying to use a RabbitMQ queue as a trigger for a Lambda function and I get the following error, this does not happen to me when I use an ActiveMQ queue. Could it be that there is no support between services?

> There was an error creating the trigger: Unsupported engine type:
> RabbitMQ (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
> InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: xxxxx; Proxy: null)

ty!

Answer (score 1):

Lambda trigger support for ActiveMQ was only recently added, and managed RabbitMQ support was only recently added. At this time there is no support for triggering Lambda functions from RabbitMQ.

Comment: how would you handle the possibility of dynamically generated queues as the event source for the lambda? In my setup queues are generated dynamically when a new user joins, so I wouldn't be able to specify the queue name ahead of time. Do you have any idea how to handle that? Thanks!

Comment: @UcheOzoemena Please ask a separate question on this site instead of adding details questions like this as a comment.

Comment: Thanks I've posted a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70366726/handing-dynamically-generated-queues-for-amazon-mq-as-an-event-source-for-lambda. I'd appreciate if you could respond :)